# BASH: unescape string

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following string:

```
"some\nstring\n..."
```

And it displays as one line when catted in bash. Further,

```
string_from_pipe | sed 's/\\\\/\\/g' # does not work
| awk '{print $0}'
| awk '{s = $0; print s}'
| awk '{s = $0; printf "%s",s}'
| echo $0  
| sed 's/\\(.)/\1/g'
# all have not worked.
```

How do I unescape this string such that it prints as:

```
some
string
```

Or even displays that way inside a file?

Comment: Where are you getting this string from? Is it a literal in your script?

Comment: It is a string I output from a cpp program that escapes all control characters

Comment: What's the output of `head -n 1 my_file_with_escaped_strings`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I cant copy paste the bytes.  suffice to say it is a string surrounded by quotations, in literal format: `"some\nstring\n with \t these \t\t kinds of things\n"`

Comment: have you tried to assign to a variable before the pipe `s="some\nstring\n..." | printf "$s\n"`

Comment: @Matts I didn't know that was possible in a pipeline...will try that

Comment: It *isn't* possible. Different parts of a pipeline run in different subshells, so they don't see each others' variables. (cc: @Matts)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I understand that now. I'd used variables to simplify some conditional statements, but they didn't use pipeline.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

POSIX `sh` [provides `printf %b`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) for just this purpose:

```
s='some\nstring\n...'
printf '%b\n' "$s"
```

...will emit:

```
some
string
...
```

More to the point, the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) explicitly suggests using `printf %b` for this purpose rather than relying on optional XSI extensions.

Comment: got it: `cat ... | xargs printf '%b\n'`

Comment: That's not really ideal. `printf '%b\n' "$(<file)"` is significantly more efficient (if using bash, where `$(<filename)` is available), *and* less buggy; `xargs` without using GNU extensions such as `-0` or `-d $'\n'` has quite a lot of surprising behaviors. (Try input with literal quotes, f/e, or spaces within the lines).

Comment: For the sake of argument, suppose it is required that I run the printf using xargs. Is the following stable? `... | xargs -I {} printf '%b\n' {}`

Comment: @donlan "Stable", in that its output won't change unexpectedly? Yes. "Correct", in that it runs the `printf '%b\n'` transformation on each line of input, without munging that input first? No. See the examples given at https://ideone.com/2QzTIa showing different ways to use `xargs` to invoke `printf '%b\n'`; only the ones using `xargs -0` or `xargs -d $'\n'` have correct output.

Comment: (BTW, that would probably make a pretty good answer, if you transformed that comment into its own SO question, or wouldn't mind if I did so).

Answer (score 5):

As you observed, `echo` does not solve the  problem:

```
$ s="some\nstring\n..."
$ echo "$s"
some\nstring\n...
```

You haven't mentioned where you got that string or which escapes are in it.

#### Using a POSIX-compliant shell's `printf`

If the escapes are ones supported by `printf`, then try:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$s"
some
string
...
```

#### Using sed

```
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
some
string
...
```

#### Using awk

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '{gsub(/\\n/, "\n")} 1'
some
string
...
```

Comment: escapes are just backslashes, output from cpp code; this does not work.  :| (stumped). getting it from a pipe

Comment: @bordeo "does not work" is too vague to be helpful.  It clearly works for me on your sample string.  Running the same string with the same command, did you get the same result or a different result?  If different, exactly how is it different?

Comment: I got exactly "some\nstring\n" -- literally.

Comment: @bordeo This works when applied correctly. How did you adapt this solution to your case?

Comment: @bordeo Please run `type printf` and tell us what prints.

Comment: @John1024 ok one sec, I got it to work, but the solution was a hack. I will run type printf and post everything as an edit to the bottom of the original post, and delete when we get a good answer.

Comment: printf is a shell builtin

Comment: @bordeo Please define "hack".

Comment: @John1024 added the edits; hack = basically, what I did with the sed statements above

Comment: @John1024 in other words, something analytically equivalent, albeit convoluted, but results in different behavior than expected = hack

Comment: @bordeo See updated answer for other approaches.  Note that the awk code added in the edit to the question is completely different from my first suggestion of shell code.  Awk and shell are different languages.

Comment: @John1024 got it--ok will try out initial solution as well

Answer (score 1):

If you have the string in a variable (say `myvar`), you can use:

```
${myvar//\\n/$'\n'}
```

For example:

```
$ myvar='hello\nworld\nfoo'
$ echo "${myvar//\\n/$'\n'}"
hello
world
foo
$
```

(Note: it's usually safer to use `printf %s <string>` than `echo <string>`, if you don't have full control over the contents of `<string>`.)

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `-e` option of `echo`?

```
$ s="some\nstring\n..." && echo -e "$s"
some
string
...
```

From the `echo` [man-page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html)

```
  -e    enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
  [...]
      \a    alert (bell)
      \b    backspace
      \c    suppress further output
      \e    escape character
      \f    form feed
      \n    new line
      \r    carriage return
      \t    horizontal tab
      \v    vertical tab
      \\    backslash
      \0nnn the character whose ASCII code is NNN (octal).  NNN can be 0 to 3 octal digits
      \xHH  the eight-bit character whose value is HH (hexadecimal).  HH can be one or two hex digits
```

Comment: `echo -e` is [required by the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) to print `-e` on output; the bash behavior this answer documents is noncompliant, and can be turned off at compile-time or runtime. It's much more reliable to use `printf '%b\n' "$s"` instead, which works the same way on *all* POSIX-compliant shells. See also the excellent answer by Stephane over at the [unix.se] question [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113).