# How to unescape a text file?

Tags: bash, terminal, cat

I have a file `log.txt` with this content:

```
systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...\r\n[    8.759274] systemd[1]:
```

When I do `cat log.txt` output is:

```
systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...\r\n[    8.759274] systemd[1]:
```

Expected output is 2 lines (`\r\n` to be replaced with visibly new line):

```
systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...
[    8.759274] systemd[1]:
```

How to achieve this in a bash terminal?

Comment: Have example command that will do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BASH: unescape string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563387/bash-unescape-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without involving any external command, you can do this using `printf '%b\n'` instead of `cat`:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(<log.txt)"

systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...
[    8.759274] systemd[1]:
```

- `%b` expands backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
- `$(<log.txt)` is bash directive to get content of `log.txt`

Comment: Thanks.. How would I 'pipe' into this command? (e.g. `cat log.txt | printf '%b\n` )?

Comment: You can avoid needless `cat` by doing `printf '%b\n' "$(<log.txt)"` and if you need further pipeline like counting lines then use: `printf '%b\n' "$(<log.txt)" | wc -l`

Comment: If you do want to use this `printf` in a pipe then use it like this: `cat log.txt | xargs -0 printf '%b'`

Comment: btw `sed` command that would work in any `sed` is `cat log.txt | sed $'s/\\\\r/\\\r/g; s/\\\\n/\\\n/g;'`

Comment: Thanks! This worked.. (`cat log.txt | xargs -0 printf '%b'`)

Comment: This worked as well: `cat log.txt | sed $'s/\\\\r/\\\r/g; s/\\\\n/\\\n/g;'`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`echo -e`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) for that:

```
echo -e $(<log.txt)
```

Comment: Nice! this worked.. I saw somewhere `echo -e` but did not know how to 'point to a file'.. Thanks..

Comment: How would I 'pipe' into this command? (e.g. `cat log.txt | echo -e`)?

Comment: Just run `echo -e $(less log.txt)`. Why would you want to pipe anything?

Comment: Because I have incoming data from a command that I store first in a log.txt.  Now thinking that I do not need intermediate log.txt file but just directly can pipe into parsing command.

Comment: That is a different question. Which means this was a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why use an interactive program like `less` when `cat` (or in-shell `$(<log.txt)` will do?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed:

```
$ cat log.txt | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/' -e 's/\\r//'
```

If this does not work, try

```
$ cat log.txt | sed -e 's/\\r//' -e 's/\\n/\
/'
```

that is, hit enter after the last backslash and complete the command in the next line.

Comment: This did not work (did not replace with newline char).

Comment: Whether or not `\n` is recognized as a literal newline depends on your implementation of `sed`.

Comment: Output for me (for `cat log.txt | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/' -e 's/\\r//'`): `systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...n[    8.759274] systemd[1]:`